# How to keep user's choice of checkboxes in the template after POST request in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django and trying to solve a simple problem. I looked through many similar questions but still is not able to find the solution.

In my template I have a few checkboxes which are built according to records in the database.

My Model is:

```
class Status(models.Model):

statusCode=models.IntegerField()
definition = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.definition}"
```

In my view I'm getting the values of checkboxes that user chose and store them in the list:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    status_list = request.POST.getlist('statuses')
```

I pass this list as a context:

```
return render(request, 'search/index.html',{"chosen_statuses": status_list,
                                            "statuses": Status.objects.all()}
```

Then I want to display results of the query keeping the checkboxes that user selected - selected.
This is my code in template:

```
<div>
   <label for="status">Include statuses: </label>
   {% for status in statuses %}
       <input type='checkbox' value='{{ status.id }}' name='statuses'
            {% if status.id in chosen_statuses %}
            checked
            {% endif %}>
       <label for='{{ status }}'>{{ status }}</label>
   {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

The list "chosen_values" contains the user's choices as needed, and the results of the query are correct. But the checkboxes are left unchecked.

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after hours, probably this a newbee mistake.
It turned out I cannot pass list to template to compare its values to query object.
In my views I should pass the query object instead (which takes list as a parameter in filter:

```
"chosen_statuses": Status.objects.filter(statusCode__in = status_list)
```

and then I adjust if statement in template:

```
            <div>
            <label for="status">Include statuses: </label>
            {% for status in statuses %}
                <input type='checkbox' value='{{ status.id }}' name='statuses' 
                {% if status in chosen_statuses %}
                checked
                {% endif %}>
                <label for='{{ status }}'>{{ status }}</label>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```